# How to get response from function to Express.js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Following is my code:

Middleware:

```
app.get('/myapp', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('mydocument').find(function (err, docs) {

        var result = checkAuthorisedUser(); //calling function checkAuthorisedUser from here

        console.log("result:" + result);
        if (docs.length > 0)
            res.json(docs);
        else
            res.json(null);
    });
});
```

Function `checkAuthorisedUser()`

```
function checkAuthorisedUser() {
    var result;
    db.collection('user').find({uid: session.uid}, function (err, docs) {        
        console.log(docs); // Here its displaying result
        result = docs;
    });    
    return result;
}
```

In above code I'm trying to call a function from middleware where I've written mongodb query to find `userid` but its not assigning `docs` to `var result` so that's why it's not returning the data and showing `undefined` in the `console.log(result)`.

I'm beginner in `express.js`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `console.log(result)` is logging an as-yet-unused variable which is why it's undefined. I presume you meant to log `docs`?

Comment: @JohnO'Mahoney: Sorry that was typo. Modified post.

Comment: @chridam: I don't think its duplicate bcz the solution I want is in `express.js` not in js, ajax or jquery

Comment: Regardless of the question tags, the fundamentals encapsulated in the answers still remain; you are trying to return a result from an asynchronous function, you need to use a callback for this.

Comment: @chridam: okay I've tried callback function `var checkAuthorisedUser = function () {    
    db.collection('user').find({dtid: session.dtid}, function (err, docs) {
        return docs;
    });
};` but still but still same issue